# C[0, 1] is not complete

Tags: functional-analysis

Define $||f||= max{|x^2 f(x)|} $ then prove that with this norm  C[0, 1] is not complete norm linear space.

Find a cauchy sequence in C[0, 1] which is not convergent with this norm

Comment: Consider the function $f \equiv -1$. Then, by your definition, $\left| \left| f \right| \right| = 0$ but $f \not\equiv 0$. There is some error in the definition of norm.

Comment: @Aniruddha Deshmukh, I changed definition of norm.. Plz try now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}n & 0 \leq x \leq 1/n \\ 1/x & 1/n \leq x  \leq 1 \end{cases}$$

Then on $x > 0,$ $f_n$ converges to $f(x) = 1/x,$ but this is not the restriction of any continuous function on $[0,1]$